# How do I send an email from python using outlook web access?

Tags: python, email, outlook, outlook-web-app

I need to send an email in python if my job fails, however due to company polices, I am only allowed to use the Outlook Web Access.  How can I connect to Outlook Web Access from python to send an email?

Comment: check these links  :[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6332577/send-outlook-email-via-python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6332577/send-outlook-email-via-python)                                                                                   [http://www.holovaty.com/writing/python-outlook-web-access/](http://www.holovaty.com/writing/python-outlook-web-access/)

Comment: did you solve thi problem? I am in the same situation.

Answer (score 2):

I can't take credit for this but I can lead you to a possible solution.

Here's the link: http://win32com.goermezer.de/content/view/227/192/
Here's the code

```
import win32com.client

s = win32com.client.Dispatch("Mapi.Session")
o = win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application")
s.Logon("Outlook2003")

Msg = o.CreateItem(0)
Msg.To = "recipient@domain.com"

Msg.CC = "more email addresses here"
Msg.BCC = "more email addresses here"

Msg.Subject = "The subject of you mail"
Msg.Body = "The main body text of you mail"

attachment1 = "Path to attachment no. 1"
attachment2 = "Path to attachment no. 2"
Msg.Attachments.Add(attachment1)
Msg.Attachments.Add(attachment2)

Msg.Send()
```

This is cool and I have to use it.
A related SO question can be found here: [Python - Send HTML-formatted email via Outlook 2007/2010 and win32com](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24650518/python-send-html-formatted-email-via-outlook-2007-2010-and-win32com?rq=1)

Comment: I should also mention that I am trying to send emails from mac/linux

Comment: Ah, I see. That's an important caveat.
I'll do some digging.

Comment: Are you still digging?

Comment: Unfortunately no, I haven't but am in a work place where it'd be reasonable to dig into this again...